# JQuery Rowgrouping spitting the same groups

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using JQuery Datatables where my HTML code is,

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                                                    id="dataTables-industryGroupFilter">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody id="industryGroupFilterDetails">
                                            </tbody>
                                            </table>
```

where I am grouping my table using below:

```
dataTableGroupIndustry.rowGrouping({bExpandableGrouping: true,iGroupingColumnIndex:3,iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex:4, sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "desc",fnGroupLabelFormat:function(label){ if(label=="" || label=="-") return "<i>Undefined</i>"+" ("+mapIndustry[""]+")"; else if(mapIndustry[label]!=null) return label+" ("+mapIndustry[label]+")"; else return label; }});
```

Everything works fine except , datatable is unnecessarily splitting the same groups. i.e I can see 2 different groups with same labels but different records. I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: can i see a screenshot ? or html code and scripts ?

Comment: You can see screenshot on this link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4NsA9OOOuY1ODJmT2RRV25KcTA/view?usp=sharing